# How Count/Sum Values Based On Multiple Conditions in Multiple Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a shipping records table  with approx. 100K rows and
I want to calculate, for each row, for each material, how many qtys were shipped in last 30 days.
As you can see in below example, calculated qty depends on "material, shipping date".
I've tried to write very basic code and couldn't find a way to apply it to all rows.

```
df[(df['malzeme']==material) & (df['cikistarihi'] < shippingDate) & (df['cikistarihi'] >= (shippingDate-30))]['qty'].sum()
```

| material | shippingDate | qty | shipped qtys in last 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 23.01.2019 | 8 | 0 |
| A | 28.01.2019 | 41 | 8 |
| A | 31.01.2019 | 66 | 49 (8+41) |
| A | 20.03.2019 | 67 | 0 |
| B | 17.02.2019 | 53 | 0 |
| B | 26.02.2019 | 35 | 53 |
| B | 11.03.2019 | 4 | 88 (53+35) |
| B | 20.03.2019 | 67 | 106 (35+4+67) |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` with `.rolling`:

```py
# convert the shippingData to datetime:
df["shippingDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["shippingDate"], dayfirst=True)

# sort the values (if they aren't already)
df = df.sort_values(["material", "shippingDate"])

df["shipped qtys in last 30 days"] = (
    df.groupby("material")
    .rolling("30D", on="shippingDate", closed="left")["qty"]
    .sum()
    .fillna(0)
    .values
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  material shippingDate  qty  shipped qtys in last 30 days
0        A   2019-01-23    8                           0.0
1        A   2019-01-28   41                           8.0
2        A   2019-01-31   66                          49.0
3        A   2019-03-20   67                           0.0
4        B   2019-02-17   53                           0.0
5        B   2019-02-26   35                          53.0
6        B   2019-03-11    4                          88.0
7        B   2019-03-20   67                          39.0
```

---

EDIT: Add `.sort_values()` before groupby

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but i think i am missing something. When i changed dates and their order, there is something wrong.

data = {'material':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
        'shippingDate':['2019-01-23', '2019-01-28', '2019-01-31', '2019-01-20', '2019-01-23', '2019-03-28', '2019-03-11', '2019-03-20'],
       'qty':[8, 41, 66, 67, 53, 35, 4, 67]}

print as below:
material shippingdate qty shipped30d
1 A 2019-01-28 41 182.0
3 A 2019-01-20 67 115.0
5 B 2019-03-28 35 0.0
7 B 2019-03-20 67 39.0

Comment: @CanerU  I think the logics is perfectly ok.  You just need to ensure the dates are in chronological order by doing `df = df.sort_values(['material', 'shippingDate'])` before the main logics.